# Hosted WMV file asking for a password to play

Tags: authentication, iis, wmv

We have a simple WMV file on our IIS server and when browsing to it we get a security pop up requesting authentication to play the file.

Everyone has read & execute but the file still requires authentication.

Is there a setting that needs to be configured to allow playing WMV file?

Comment: What's playing the app? an `<embed>` in a web page? separate media app? VLC? media player? Winamp?

Comment: Windows media player is playing the file. it's not embeded in a web page we are calling the wmv file directly in the url. If I enter my credentials the file is being played however we don't want the users to provide credentials. This is an internal application to our organisation it's not on the web.

Comment: It seems to be an UNC Password problem. I got the message 'The following child nodes also define the value of the "UNCPassword" property, which overrides the value you have just set ...' how to I remove that security ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by adding an AnonymousUserPass to the meta data file using The IIS 6.0 Resource Kit Tools
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17275